# While pushing a viewcontroller there is a jerk in animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

For pushing a view controller I'm using following code. On tap of `UITableViewCell` need to push `DetailViewController`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row)
    {
        NSDate *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
        DetailViewController *controller = [DetailViewController new];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Now problem is I get a jerk while animating. Refer to screenshot

[image]

Comment: What does `DetailViewController` do it its `init`, `viewDidLoad` & `viewWillAppear` methods?

Comment: init and willAppear not implemented

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [[self.navigationController navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}

Comment: any warnings for constraints in `DetailViewController`?

Comment: no warnings in storyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its because of transparency. just set a background color for your viewcontroller. thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're doing something "heavy" on the main thread, while loading DetailViewController.

Could you show us what are you doing in DetailViewController?

Comment: noting at all. Its just a basic view controller from story board

Answer (score 0):

I think there is issue with allocating object and pushing same object.

Do the following changes, it will work fine.

**Your code** :

```
 DetailViewController *controller = [DetailViewController new];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

**Replace** :

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                         bundle: nil];

MyViewController *controller = (MyViewController*)[mainStoryboard 
                    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"<your Storyboard ID>"];
```

it will work fine at my end.

Hope this help you.