# Standard show segue animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewcontroller

I'm pretty new to iOS and created a standard show detail segue. Now it works but the result is a bit choppy. I navigate from a UITableViewController to a ViewController but the animation kind of just 'keeps hanging' half way trough.

I've tried making a screen cap of it:

[image]

But since the capturing software is also a bit crappy the entire .gif is choppy.

The choppiness occurs about halfway trough the animation and continues just a moment after. Is this standard behavior? Or am I doing something wrong?

The navigation is as follows:

From UITableViewController - Show (e.g. push) segue -> UIViewController

Comment: How does it look on your device, does it look the same?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Currently I don't have access to a device. The emulator normally runs smoothly though.

Comment: @4esterUA Thanks for finding that! I couldn't find it because it was a little hard to troubleshoot this question (the problem is quite hard to explain). If you want you can put that as an answer!

Comment: Glad that it was helpful for you. Posted an answer.

Comment: @TimKranen is this issue solved for you ? I am also facing it. I am unable to find the reason. This happens for my swift version of the project.

Comment: @padam Yes, the accepted answer is right. It's an issue with the simulator. On a real device this doesn't happen.

Comment: @TimKranen But this is happening on my iphone4S too not just simulator. Was it working fine for you on real device ?

Comment: @padamthapa Yes it did. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks same as in this question [While pushing a viewcontroller there is a jerk in animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30098922/while-pushing-a-viewcontroller-there-is-a-jerk-in-animation) Unfortunately, it not solved yet. Pretty sure this can be simulator issue\bug. I had same issue with collectionView scrolling (lags on simulator) but it works well on device (even on slow one).